# How to select this text  using pure javascript, no jquery?

Tags: javascript

I need to select some text using javascript (no jquery), and Im not sure how to do it. I need to select the text ('Hello World') in myClass element before the first child element. Here are two examples, sometimes it will be an `<img>` tag as the first element and sometimes it will be a `<br>` tag. I also need to select the text between the `<br>` tags.

```
<p class="myClass" style="padding: 5px;">  
    Hello World

    <img src="http://xyz.com/image.gif">                                            
    <br>
    30-12-2011 19:45
    <br>
    Testing
    <br>
</p>





<p class="myClass" style="padding: 5px;">  
    Hello World                                                                         
    <br>
    30-12-2011 19:45
    <br>
    Testing
    <br>
</p>
```

**Edit note:** I also need to select the other text nodes in myClass. And note that sometimes there will be an `<img>` as one of the child elements and sometimes there won't.

So I would like to end up with

```
var a = 'Hello World'
var b = '30-12-2011 19:45'
var c = 'Testing'
```

Anyone able to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript HTML DOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elem = document.getElementsByClassname("myClass")[0],
    txtNode = elem.childNodes[0],
    txtNodeValue = txtNode.nodeValue;
console.log(txtNodeValue);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/5pfgp/).

We select the element by its class (`[0]` just tells it to select the first element in the matched set) and then look for its first child node. In your case this would be the text node, so all we have to do from there is get the nodeValue.

Comment: @John It sounds like you have a different question altogether. This (seven year old, btw) post answered the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Not really sure what you want. If you want to get all the text, then use:

```
var text = element.innerText || element.textContent;
```

If you want to get the text in several pieces, then you have to iterate over all child nodes and extract the text nodes:

```
var texts = [],
   children = element.childNodes;


for(var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
   var node = children[i];
   if(node.nodeType === 3) {
       var text = node.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
       if(text.length > 0) {
           texts.push(text);
       }
   }
}
```

This would not concatenate consecutive text nodes though, which can occur if you inserted new text nodes or split text nodes with JavaScript. In this case, you could do this:

```
var texts = [''],
    children = element.childNodes,
    new_bucket = false,
    bucket = 0;

for(var i = 0, len = children.length; i < len; i++) {
    var node = children[i];
    if(node.nodeType === 1 && new_bucket) {
        new_bucket = false;
        texts[++bucket] = '';
    }
    else if(node.nodeType === 3) {
        var text = node.nodeValue.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
        if(text.length > 0) {
            new_bucket = true;
            texts[bucket] += text
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This will get the **first** element with the class `myClass` and the **first** `text node` of that element:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue
```

Here is a great [article](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/intro.html) explaining.

You will most likely want to `trim` the string as well to remove white-space. You can add the following to give you trim functionality:

```
if(typeof String.prototype.trim !== 'function') {
  String.prototype.trim = function() {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ''); 
  }
}
```

...and use it as such:

```
var trimmedString = document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue.trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

I dont know how regular your example is but you can use the document object to interact with the DOM.

select the myClass elements

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass');
```

then take the first index , its childNodes and the first index of that which is a text node

```
var nodes = elements[0].childNodes;

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++)
{
    var node = nodes[i],
        text;
    // loop over the nodes and see if its as textnode.  Then trim and skip empty strings
    if(node.nodeType === 3) {
        text = node.textContent.trim();
        if(text) {
            alert(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/kgdnR/1/

```
var abc = [].filter.call((document.getElementsByClassName("myClass")[0].childNodes), function(node) {

    if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && node.nodeValue.trim().length) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}).map(function(node) {
    return node.nodeValue.trim();
});

var a = abc[0],
    b = abc[1],
    c = abc[2];

console.log(a, b, c);
```

Can be made work in IE but if you wanted that you might as well use jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('test')
```

to select the elements using the class name.
select the element you want (it returns an array), and then use
    nodeValue
which will return the text.

Answer (score 0):

With using XPath expression:

```
var contextNode = document.body;
var node, textNodes = [];
var search = document.evaluate('.//text()', contextNode, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE);
while(node = search.iterateNext()) textNodes.push(node);
```

Answer (score -2):

*Selecting* text as asked by the OP:

```
var my_class = document.getElementsByClassName('myClass')[0];
window.getSelection().selectAllChildren(my_class);
```